# Dynamically change URL of the page based on date in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, strapi

I have webinars running every few days and I want to change the webinar URL of the generated page from let's say:

[www.example.com/webinar-example](http://www.example.com/webinar-example)

to

[www.example.com/webinar-example-recording](http://www.example.com/webinar-example-recording)

after the webinar has passed.

The problem is that the gatsby-node.js is running only during the build time so I can't dynamically change the path of the generated page if the webinar has passed, I would have to rebuild the application to apply the new URL.

I can't figure out whether or not should I do the dynamic route change in the page component itself or in the gatsby-ssr.js file maybe.

One thing that came to my mind would be some sort of conditional CRON job that would check if the webinar has passed and then rebuilt the application but I am not sure if that would be the best approach.

Would there be some let's say proper Gatsby way of doing this?

How would you guys tackle this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Client-Only Routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/) feature of Gatsby to add support for the later URL.

If triggering a fresh build each day does what you need, though, that's simple enough to set up, whether that's through a cron job or an external service like [Pipedream](https://docs.pipedream.com/workflows/steps/triggers/#cron-scheduler) to trigger a webhook prompting a re-build (a la Netlify).